# Send message to new user only in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Currently I'm writing my first Telegram bot.
It should send a message to new users.
Other users should not get spammed by these messages and therefore I want to send it only to the new user.

I already have:

```py
def switch(update, context):
    try:
        for new_member in update.message.new_chat_members:
            callback_id = str(new_member.id)
            # This is where I'm stuck

    except AttributeError:
        pass


def main():
    updater = Updater(str(TOKEN), use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.chat(int(CHAT_ID)), switch))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It runs until the commented line when a new user enters the chat.
Now I'm searching for the method to send a message to the new user only.

Comment: How do you plan to send the message? in the same chat or in a personal chat between the bot and the user? The latter will be hardly done because bots can't initiate conversations with users.

Comment: I wanted to send a personal welcome message inside the group chat. This message should be only visible to the new User.